# Azure Logic App calculate Total Sum of a column from a CSV file

Tags: azure, csv, azure-logic-apps, csvtojson

I'm using an Azure Logic App to get the blob contents from my storage account. The Blob-file is in .CSV file. The CSV file consists of a few columns and multiple rows. The file is basically an Invoice file which consists of a column named "PreTaxCost". I need to calculate the Total Sum of the all the entries within the "PreTaxCost" column in the CSV file to get the TOTAL BILLING COST.

[image: Screenshot of the csv file (opened with notepad++)]
Any idea on how I can achieve this using Azure Logic Apps?
Thanks!

Comment: Hi, do you think it takes too much time and too complex if do the add number in for each loop ?

Comment: Maybe I can provide another solution for add number, I just thought it. I'm not sure if it can work, need to do some research and then provide the solution.

Comment: Hi @HuryShen the thing is I cant use a third-party connector. Thats the problem.
Your solution of the for_each loop for adding number each loop was perfect! But I cannot use a paid connector to convert CSV to JSON  :/

Comment: If you want another solution to add number, maybe I can provide it. But I'm afraid I can do nothing to help you parse csv to json. If you do not want to use third-party connector, you can just write code by yourself to convert the csv to json. You can create a azure function and write convert code in it and invoke the function in you logic app. As far as I know, there isn't a connector which can help us parse csv in logic app(except third-party connector).

Comment: I'm trying to write code to parse csv for you. If success, I will post the solution below. Maybe I will provide solution tomorrow.

Comment: May I know the column name is `PreTaxCost` or `Pre tax cost`, I need to do some test in my code. The space in the column name may have impact.

Comment: And is there any space between the headers ? The header of csv is `InstanceID,MeterID,UsageQuantity,ResourceLocation,PreTaxCost` or `InstanceID, MeterID, UsageQuantity, ResourceLocation, PreTaxCost` ?

Comment: Hi @HuryShen It is is PreTaxCost. There's a space between each column name like InstanceID, MeterID, UsageQuantity, ResourceLocation, PreTaxCost. 
I'll post a screenshot of the CSV file in the post

Comment: Could you please provide a screen of the csv header(open the csv with notepad++ but not with excel) ?

Comment: I will do some further test and provide the solution tomorrow.

Comment: Yes @HuryShen sure I'll do that. I'll send the new screenshot in sometime. Thanks so much!

Comment: Hey @HuryShen sorry there's no space between the column names. I've added the screenshot of the csv file opened with notepadd++

Comment: The solution provided by user20200509 is almost same with mine. You can refer to it to solve your problem.

Comment: Hey @HuryShen so I added the code below to the inline code in the logic app. In "<csv content>" I'm calling the "FILE_CONTENT" of the blob from "get blob contents" trigger. 
But the output I'm getting is 0

Comment: The line in code should be `var content = workflowContext.actions.Get_blob_content.outputs.body;`. If your "Get blob content" is named "Get blob content 2", the line should be `var content = workflowContext.actions.Get_blob_content_2.outputs.body;`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/224130/discussion-between-sd4-and-hury-shen).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to our conversation and your requirements. Since you can't solve a problem when doing add number in JS inline code, so provide the add number steps below for your reference:

**1.** Delete the last few lines of the code in JS inline code action, return `json` directly.

**2.** Initialize two variables `sum` and `tempItem`.

[image]

**3.** Use "For each" to loop the `Result` from JS inline code action, and do set variable action in the "For each" loop.

[image]

**4.** The expression of `fx add(...)` is `add(variables('tempItem'), float(items('For_each')?['PreTaxCost']))`. If your "For each" loop named `For each 2`, the expression should be `add(variables('tempItem'), float(items('For_each_2')?['PreTaxCost']))`.

**5.** Please do not forget enable `Concurrency Control`, and set `Degree of Parallelism` as `1`. Then run the logic app, you can get the sum result.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to convert csv to json in Azure logic app, you can use `Execute JavaScript Code` action to run js code to implement it. The JS code is as below

```
function csvToJson(csv){

  var lines=csv.split("\r\n");

  var result = [];

  var headers=lines[0].split(",");
  for(var i=0; i<headers.length; i++){
    //remove space
    headers[i]=headers[i].split(" ").join("")
   
  }
  for(var i=1;i<lines.length;i++){

      var obj = {};
      var currentline=lines[i].split(",");

      for(var j=0;j<headers.length;j++){
          obj[headers[j]] = currentline[j];
      }

      result.push(obj);

  }

  return JSON.stringify(result);;
}
var content = "<csv content>";

var json = JSON.parse(csvToJson(content));
var sum = 0;

json.forEach(item=>{
    sum = sum + parseInt(item.PreTaxCost);
});
return sum;
```

For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/logic-apps/logic-apps-add-run-inline-code) and [here](http://techslides.com/convert-csv-to-json-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks for your response! I have a "get blob contents" trigger. Do I need to specify the path of the blob(csv file) in the above code ?